# Regex with at least 3 alpha and allows numerics and specials chars

Tags: javascript, regex

The regexp what i'm searching for is :

- must contains 3 alpha chars at first
- allows numerics values
- allows dash, dot and underscore

Examples :

test1546 = OK

vqa._96 = OK

1test_ = KO

_test1546 = KO

Thank's a lot! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]{3}[\w.-]*$/
```

Explanation:

- The `^` matches the start of the string.
- The `$` matches the end of the string.
- The `[a-zA-Z]{3}` means match three letters.
- The `\w` matches `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.